# Embeddable common lisp only builds .fasc not .o

Tags: c, compiler-errors, lisp, common-lisp, ecl

The [documentation](https://common-lisp.net/project/ecl/) for ECL suggests that

```
(compile-file "hello.lisp" :system-p t)
```

should produce a .o file however I instead get a .fasc file and the ouput

```
>  (compile-file "hello.lisp" :system-p t)
;;; Compiling hello.lisp;;; Compiling #<input stream hello.lisp>#P"hello.fasc"
NIL
NIL
```

Comment: Does calling `EXT:INSTALL-C-COMPILER` first help? Is the value of `C:*CC*` a compiler that is actually installed on your system?

Comment: @jkiiski Running EXT:INSTALL-C-COMPILER returns this `> (EXT:INSTALL-C-COMPILER)
;;; Loading #P"C:/Program Files (x86)/ECL/cmp.fas"

Condition of type: SIMPLE-ERROR
LOAD: Could not load file #P"C:/Program Files (x86)/ECL/cmp.fas" (Error: "The operation completed successfully.
")
Available restarts:

1. (RESTART-TOPLEVEL) Go back to Top-Level REPL.

Broken at SI:BYTECODES. [Evaluation of: (EXT:INSTALL-C-COMPILER)] In: #<process TOP-LEVEL>.` and then the compiling results in the same output.

Comment: Does the file `C:/Program Files (x86)/ECL/cmp.fas` exist? Might be some kind of a Windows permission issue preventing it from being loaded too, but I'm not that familiar with Windows. Try running ECL as administrator to see if it succeeds in loading the file then.

Comment: @jkiiski It does exist and I ran the application as administrator, attributes suggests some of it is read only but unchecking it makes it just recheck itself.